# how to write my htaccess code to rewrite multi country and language

Tags: php, .htaccess

how to write my htaccess code to rewrite multi country and language
I am week in htaccess. now my company want to design a commercial website with multi country and language setting.
Need help .

```
http://ca.hello.com/en 
=>
http://www.hello.com/?country=ca&language=en

------------------------
http://ca.hello.com/en/help.html
=>
http://www.hello.com/index.php?main_page=help&country=ca&language=en
```

Comment: Check out `content negotiation` in the Apache Config settings. It should be done in `httpd.conf` though. To make the changes in `.htaccess` `AllowOverride` would need to be enabled. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't test it but try this and let me know if it doesn't work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.hello\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)?[.html]$ http://www.hello.com/index.php?main_page=$2&country=%1&language=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I am having trouble using the above stated code. I would highly appreciate if you could explain it a little because it doesn't seem to work for me. Thanks